# Please disable enter to submit comments on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed

Enter-to-submit-comments interferes with Japanese input.  It's vital that it be disabled on Japanese.SE.  It's been disabled on our main site for a long time; see this bug report:

[Please disable Enter to submit comments](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/please-disable-enter-to-submit-comments)

I thought it was disabled on meta, too, but apparently it isn't right now.  Unfortunately, [this is interfering with our users' ability to post comments](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/how-valuable-are-answers-by-native-speakers-that-are-mainly-based-on-their-subje#comment3275_1332) (unless they happen to be less than 15 characters long, since enter can't submit a comment below the minimum length).

#### Please disable enter-to-submit-comments on meta.japanese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done, should be working the same as on the main site now.

Comment: Consider also implementing [the bugfix documented here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217498) (use a `keydown` handler instead of a `keyup` handler), which should allow submitting comments with the Enter key while also retaining IME compatibility.