# Strange Characters in Native Post

Tags: discussion

[metaを](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/encouraging-participation-from-native-japanese-speakers-translating-posts)読みながら、このコメントを見ました：

> ... 僕なんかは日本語の母語話者だからといって日本語についてきちんと理解している/質問に答えられるわけじゃないというのを痛感し‌​ているので（そのために見に来ているようなところもあります笑），どちら向きにせよきちんと学ばれた方というのは貴重な戦力だろうと思います．ベータ版である上日本語につい‌​て扱える唯一のSEであることもあって，質問の幅はかなり広めに見られているような気がしますね．あとは「良くない質問はコミュニティで淘汰できる」という自信もあるのでし‌​ょう．とりあえずは質の良い質問だけ相手にすることにして，よほど何様のつもりだとなるような質問についてはここメタで別個に討議する，という感じでいかがでしょうか．そう‌​いう質問も問題ないよ，...

気になっているところは「し‌​」などです。私のパソコンに、それは「し」ではなく、左に「し」右に四角のものになります。「し‌」を使うのはわざとだ思っています。普通の書き方と比べて、どのヌアンスがありますか。

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you're using Google Chrome on a Mac, which introduced this tofu <s>feature</s> bug on Jan 29th.

You can track the progress of this issue on [their issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=421272). There's a related post on [meta.ja.so](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1660/30), which explains the technical details of the issue in Japanese.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not seeing anything unusual about the text you quoted, but a bit of spelunking leads me to believe that you're seeing [U+200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) being rendered as a box rather than being invisible because of a font issue or something similar. Are the places you're seeing them (in the original comment, not in the text below) the ends of the lines as I've broken them up here?

> ... 僕なんかは日本語の母語話者だからといって日本語についてきちんと理解している/質問に答えられるわけじゃないというのを痛感し‌
>
> ​ているので（そのために見に来ているようなところもあります笑），どちら向きにせよきちんと学ばれた方というのは貴重な戦力だろうと思います．ベータ版である上日本語につい‌​
>
> て扱える唯一のSEであることもあって，質問の幅はかなり広めに見られているような気がしますね．あとは「良くない質問はコミュニティで淘汰できる」という自信もあるのでし‌
>
> ​ょう．とりあえずは質の良い質問だけ相手にすることにして，よほど何様のつもりだとなるような質問についてはここメタで別個に討議する，という感じでいかがでしょうか．そう‌​
>
> いう質問も問題ないよ，...

If so, there's not much Japanese about this; if I had to guess, perhaps the user wrote his comment in a text editor (perhaps because the enter-submits-comments issue hadn't been fixed at the time) that is wont to automatically add these things and then copied it over to Meta. The fact that they show up every ~80 characters suggests that maybe the text editor in question was automatically adding non-joiners at linewraps or something.

Comment: Or maybe it's this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170970/

Comment: Other comments that should presumably have strange boxes on them if this is in fact the issue you're having: http://data.stackexchange.com/japanese/query/274079

Comment: It is indeed so. Thanks! ... I should delete the question right? (no longer about language)

Comment: @virmaior Maybe flag for migration to meta?