# How to "Signal" Willingness to Help With Language Barrier Issues

Tags: discussion

## English

**Background:**
Given the current composition of the community and nature of many posted questions, it is only natural that many users assume answers are to be in English.  They may further (and I fear rightfully) assume that answers not posted in near-native-level English will be poorly received. As a result, we might be losing both answers from (and new community members in) native Japanese speakers who would like to participate but may not be confident enough in their English abilities.  Also, I tend to agree with [this post](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/encouraging-participation-from-native-japanese-speakers-translating-posts) that having as much of the site be bilingual as possible would be a good thing.  However, valid concerns were raised about whether proactively editing translations into others' posts might go against the "respect the original author" rule to some degree.

**The Question(s):**
1)  Would it be useful to establish a "shortlist" (or perhaps "sub-community") of people who are willing to collaborate towards a bilingual site?  By this, I mean some way to signal to other members of the community-at-large that a given person (let's call them a "volunteer"):

- consents to their own posts being edited to add translations
- consents to their own posts' alternate language version being edited, even heavily
- is willing to collaborate on posts (even before they are made, eg via chat) such that the posting is bilingual.

For example, if I decide to "volunteer", since I am a native English speaker,  it would mean that I don't mind advanced Japanese speakers adding Japanese translations to my questions and answers.  I might try to post Japanese versions myself, and would be happy to have an advanced Japanese speaker correct them.  I also welcome people to consult with me on English usage if they are trying to write a question or answer with an English version.  A native Japanese speaker could "volunteer", indicating that they want to help in equivalent ways with Japanese.

2) In what ways can this "signal" be implemented?  Ideally, potential new users of the site would know such a signal exists.  Just to get started, some methods that might sort-of work:

- Volunteers could put a code word and/or link-to-meta in their own user profile, eg "お手伝いします（英語）" or something.
- Volunteers could comment on a specific meta post that would keep a running list of volunteers.
- .. etc ..

## 日本語

**背景**
現在のコミュニティーの構成や質問の性質を考えると、ユーザーが「英語で回答しなければならない」と思い込むのは当然のことだと思います。さらに、回答はきれいな英語で書かないと評価されないだろうと考えてしまうかもしれません（残念ながらそれも無理のないことだと思います）。その結果、参加したいけれど自分の英語に自信がないという日本人のメンバーは回答しなくなり、コミュニティーから徐々に離れていってしまうかもしれません。できるだけJLSEをバイリンガルにしようという[この投稿](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/encouraging-participation-from-native-japanese-speakers-translating-posts)の主張に賛成しますが、積極的に他のメンバーの投稿に訳を付けるのは「投稿者の意思を尊重せよ」という規則に違反する、という意見も妥当だと思います。

**質問**
１)　JLSEをバイリンガルにしたいと思う人の一覧表（もしくは、サブコミュニティー）を作るというのはどうでしょうか？具体的にいうと、一覧に載るということは以下のことを意味します。

- 自分の投稿に訳が付けられることに同意する
- 投稿の訳が他のメンバーによって編集されることに同意する（大規模な編集でも）
- 投稿をバイリンガルにするため、他のメンバーと協力する用意がある

例えば私が一覧に載ると、英語のネイティブスピーカーであるため、「私の質問と回答に和訳を付けて、または既存の和訳を編集してください」や「質問や回答などを投稿する際、遠慮なく英語について私に相談してください」などを意味します。日本語のネイティブスピーカーの場合は同様に、英訳を付けてください、和訳について私に相談してください、などを意味します。

２) このシステムをどうやって実施すればいいですか？理想的には、新しいユーザーが初めて投稿しようとする時にすでにこのシステムについて知っているといいのですが、とりあえず以下に例を挙げてみると。。

- プロフィール欄に書く（例：「Helper(Japanese)」）、またはmetaの投稿へのリンクを貼る。
- metaの特定の投稿にコメントする。
- その他。。

Comment: How about making a wiki answer to this post a volunteer list?

Comment: Added one, and very open to suggestions/edits.  I've also edited my own profile as an attempt at a "prototype" of the profile solution (and we can use links both in profiles and in the list to cross-link, if we want).  I worry that these two methods are unlikely to reach new/potential users though, so definitely hoping someone will post a better idea!

Comment: Hi, I was expecting to read other people's opinion first, but it seems that not many participants in this meta post despite being viewed almost 170 times. Does this meta post welcome answers by new members like me? My concern is that newbies opinion may not be appropriate or might be inconsiderate in this kind of discussions.

Comment: @clearkimura I would definitely love to hear ideas from any and all members. I am not exactly a veteran of this stack either, so if newer members posting is a problem, we are both in trouble.  Please feel free to post an answer, comments, etc.

Answer (score 4):

名簿 (The List)

ボランティアに参加してもいいという方は、ご自分の名前を以下に記してください。
Please feel free to edit yourself in if you wish to volunteer.

---

日本語のボランティア (Volunteers for Japanese):

- [broccoli forest](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/7810/broccoli-forest)
- [Yosh](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/4223/?tab=profile)

---

英語のボランティア (Volunteers for English):

- [WeirdlyCheezy](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/14598/weirdlycheezy?tab=profile)
- [Blavius](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/9749/blavius)
- [Sjiveru](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/3639/sjiveru)

Comment: 「英語のボランティア」というと、英語を直してもらいたい人じゃなくて英語が母国語の人だということですね？

Comment: @Sjiveru　英語のボランティアというのは、条件として、１）英語が母国語か、または高級レベルか、とりあえず自分自身がある事、　２）英語の関係に支援したい事（投稿の英語版の関係に相談の依頼を受けたり、編集したり、書いたりしたい事）　３）自分の投稿は、日本語のボランティアが日本語版を事由に編集したり追加したりしても大丈夫。

Comment: 何故かちゃんとしたフォーマッチングができない。。。

Comment: それは、一行のあとで、二回空白' 'を叩き入れれば、line breakがそこで入ります。そのように編集させていただきました。ボランティアしてくれてありがとうございます

Comment: こちらこそ教えてありがとうございます！